# research in special function with Lie algebra

Tags: soft-question, special-functions, lie-algebras, advice

First of all, I don't know if this is the right place to ask about this. If not, please direct me somewhere I can get more help.

I have to research in the field of special functions with a lie algebra
There are some previous titles in this area to clarify what I mean

> 1) The Lie algebra of certain generating functions involving the modified hypergeometric polynomial
>
> 2) Lie- Theoretic of Some Generating Functions of Two Variable Laguerre Polynomials
>
> 3) Some Generating Functions of Jacobi Polynomials with New Parameter Lie-Group

what are the areas of this branch of mathematics and what are its uses in our lives

For the people of Experience Is this area a fertile field in which to search

With thanks for all the help

Comment: You are more likely to get a useful Answer if you narrow the scope of your Question.  It might be helpful to provide links to those previous Questions (if that's what you are referring to).  This site uses MarkDown notation for many aspects of formatting posts.  See the "help" link for editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at Vilenkin's introductory 1968 book on Representation Theory and Special Functions.  Then look at his 3 volumes on the same subject with a more detailed treatment.